# Как правильно изучать ЯП по книгам?

Tags: любой-язык

Вопрос возможно и глупый, но в свою умеренность нужный. Читая книгу по android программированию, я задался вопросом: а правильно и эффективно ли я провожу время?Так как не особо много запоминается на утро,ибо все свободное время уходит на проект,а вечером лежа почему бы не почитать.
Как вы проходили/проходите обучение по ЯП ? 
Если вопрос не соответствует рамкам форума - я удалю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обучение почти всему, в том числе программированию, состоит из двух неразрывно связанных между собой аспектов: теория и практика.

Теория позволяет не совершать часть ошибок и не изобретать велосипеды. А практика, во-первых, позволяет закрепиться в памяти новым знаниям, во-вторых, выявляет пробелы в этих самых знаниях.

> Правильно и эффективно ли я провожу время?

Вопрос в эффективности обучения можно ставить только по сравнению с чем-то.

Теория по сравнению с теория+практика - не эффективно.

Теория по сравнению с практикой без теории - вопрос сложный, имхо эффективнее, но не сильно.

Книги по сравнению с онлайн-учебниками - в среднем одинаково, вопрос в личный предпочтениях бумага vs монитор.

Книги по сравнению с отдельными вопросам на форумах - эффективно.

> Как вы проходили/проходите обучение по ЯП?

Первый ЯП я учил в школе: 20 минут теории, 20 минут практики. По одному оператору за раз. Следующий подход через неделю.

Все последующие языки изучал по книгам/онлайн документации:

1. Читаю часть про синтаксис и операторы.
2. Начинаю читать код реальных проектов на этом языке.
3. Дочитываю книгу.
4. Опять читаю код. Каждый раз натыкаясь на незнакомое слово открываю справочник по языку. Как правило уже не тот, по которому изучал.
5. Начинаю писать код. При возникновении ошибок/вопросов открываю справочник по языку.

**UPD**

Как правильно заметил insolor, мой опыт изучения первого языка не эффективен.

Если есть возможность, то для первого ЯП, имхо, лучше сделать так:

- Теория по одному оператору/разделу. Обычно 10-30 минут.
- Практика сразу же после теории. От 20 минут до усталости/скуки/лимита времени.
- От 1 до 5 подходов в день, по мере сил и свободного времени.
- Повторять ежедневно, при возможности.

Comment: Я бы еще добавил, что "20 минут теории, 20 минут практики. По одному оператору за раз. Следующий подход через неделю." - не эффективно. Даже для первого языка. Если в промежутках между подходами ничего не пробовать с опережением программы, то это только имитация обучения.

Comment: @insolor, да, вы правы. Нас таких, осиливших программирование по этой методики оказалось 3 из 100

Answer (score -1):

Звучит как бы хочу научиться бегать лёжа на диване. Ответ прост. Если хотите что либо изучить прочтение моего ответа или книжки мало. Вы должны выполнять задания в вашей книги для закрепления материала, но и это ничего не гарантирует. Самообразование это хорошо - дешево, доступно. Но вот с экспертизой беда не кому показать и спросить, иначе это не самообразование. Научиться программированию можно только программируя - извините за тафталогию. Нужно весь материал пропустить через себя и в перед к покорению вершин знаний. Это тяжело, но другого варианта нет. Лучше гор могут быть только горы, на которых я (в данном случае это так, покорять неизведанное вам ещё рано) не бывал.